# Splitting matrix into columns

Tags: matlab, split

I ve got a matrix and i want to split is in the columns vectors. I want to have as output the
above vectors  [a b c d e f g h k l m n o p q r s t u] and as an input the matrix A. is there any idea?

Comment: Are you sure you want to do that?  Having 21 separate variable names doesn't sound very useful.

Comment: 10 questions asked, and you haven't accepted **a single one**. No thanks, pass.

Comment: yea i m sure about this. I want to split into 19. Any idea except the standard a = A(:,1)...

Comment: Thanks for comment Junuxx, my fault, not to accept answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this by converting your matrix to a cell array as follows:

```
M = rand(4);            % create a 4x4 random example matrix
C = num2cell(M,1);      % convert every column to a cell
[a,b,c,d] = deal(C{:}); % assign to variables a...d
```

This results in four column vectors `a, b, c, d`. Add more letters as needed.

I'm not really sure why you would want to do this though, I think it's probably more efficient to just index your original matrix with the column number you need.